# Avrdude inconsistent readings

Tags: firmware, arduino

I have a problem with this dude and i don't know what to do to make him do a consistent reading or to figure out which reading is the perfect one
I'm trying to read my own arduino uno which has a sample sketch i read it fine and the reading completes perfectly.but the problem is when i read the file more than 3 times the 4 files i got are different.first one has data only until 870 and has some string characters (which exist in serial print) second file has data until Hex 1570. And the third one has data until 1570 plus at the end of the file (i think it is the bootloader section). 
The fourth file is completely full but after 1570 it seams that the data is repeated.( I think this is the correct one since my example file has only 4 lines repeated to fill up the entire program memory) 
The problem is why avrdude doesn't read the same reading each time.
I wanted to show some pictures but i think that this is clear enough to understand the issue